# Counting rows on a datagrid and adding it as a new column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf, datagrid

I want to basically go this is row 1, row 2, 3, 4...until the last row and add that as a new column on my datagrid table, I am not trying to find the total amount of rows.

Here is my current code (I think this is terribly wrong but this is a lot of new code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            string rowNum = table.Rows[i].ToString();
            table.Columns.Add("Book num", typeof(string), rowNum);

        }
```

[image: Instead of having BookingID I want to replace it with Booking number which will use row numbers.]

Comment: What is the problem you're facing exactly?

Comment: There is no errors, I just cannot figure how to add this function. I want to be able to count the row number and replace it with BookingID or add it as a new column.

Comment: I'm just not sure I understand the problem. You wanting to create a column in a table for every row within that same table? (in your example above that would add 8 new columns)

Comment: I'm guessing you want to add a column that shows the row number?  Is that correct?

Comment: I can see why you think that, how ive written my code, I just want a single column to be added which keeps track of the row number.

Comment: @Stewbob yes that is exactly it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will add 1 new column to your table, and then populate each row in that column with the index number of that row.

If you don't want to start with `0`, just change `int i = 0;` to `int i = 1;`

```
table.Columns.Add("Book num", typeof(string));
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
  dr["Book num"] = i;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) there is a slight problem, if I add it at the start of  table it just comes out blank, but if I add it at the end it isnt blank, I think this is due to table not being loaded yet.

Comment: You can add the column before you add the other columns to your table.  But don't populate that column until you have added all the data (rows) to the table.  There are two steps here:  1. Create the column in the table.  2.  Put data in the rows in that column.   Those two steps don't have to happen at the same time.

Comment: Thank you again! Everything is working the way I want now.

Answer (score 1):

Try for total rows,

```
     int TotalRows = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
              TotalRows = 1;
            }
             else
             {
               TotalRows + = i;  
             }        
            string rowNum = table.Rows[i].ToString();
            table.Columns.Add("Book num", typeof(string), rowNum);
           }
```